# NHibernate: set entity from transient object based on unique field

Tags: nhibernate, entity, transient

My application obtains transient objects.

```
MyClass
  Id
  Name
  OtherData
```

Mapping is like *Id* is identifier and *Name* has unique constraint in database.
The transient object has no *Id* yet of course, but has fulfilled *Name* property and all other properties.
So I can write a criteria to get the entity from database based on that unique field.

**How can I easily set other data of the entity by values from transient object to update the entity?**

Suppose the class from which the transient and entity objects are created has complex structure and contains
other classes or collections of other classes.
Suppose also that there are lot of such types in the system which has unique field and should be processed in the same way.

It seems I have to write some recursive routine and via reflection set the values :-( Or is such routine already implemented? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703152/using-automapper-by-jimmy-bogard-with-nhibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) should do the job for you.

Comment: I just tested AutoMapper for this case and it works perfectly, thanks guys!