# Update model from view model

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mvvm

What's the usual way to update a NHibernate entity from a view model?

I have a view model editor where all of my data is displayed, which is fetched via a repository that returns a DTO. The DTO properties are then mapped to my view model properties. I could update my entity if I fetched it again, updated the select property required

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual approach is to have an `EditXViewModel` which handles change tracking for `XViewModel` and includes a `SaveCommand` which does the actual entity update. This ensures users can undo changes made without having to remember what they were in the database (it also cuts down on the number of transactions).

The following articles were immensely helpful when I started down this same path:

- [Nhibernate and WPF: ViewModels and Views](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/08/19/nhibernate-and-wpf-viewmodels-and-views.aspx)
- [Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, those articles don't talk about taking a view model with the edited data and saving it. Is the only option to telling NHibernate to get the entity by id, making the changes from the view model then saving it? This is the only part confusing me.

Comment: @gcso: Ah, well that clarifies things a bit. Usually in my `SaveCommand` I will Load the given item, make the changes, then commit the transaction.

Comment: @gcso: Alternatively, if you are not keeping the session open you can issue a session update (to reattach it) on the model object, perform the changes, then commit it and close the session.

Answer (score 3):

You could use AutoMapper, which is especially easy if the view models closely match the entities.

[How to simply map an NHibernate ISet to IList using AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703152/using-automapper-by-jimmy-bogard-with-nhibernate)